# How can I get markdown to format this code properly?

Tags: c, formatting, markdown

Here is some code I could not get to format properly in markdown, this is straight C code, pasted into the text box with the '4 spaces' format to denote code:

```
#define PRINT(x, format, ...) \
if ( x ) { \
    if ( debug_fd != NULL ) { \
        fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
    else { \
        fprintf(stdout, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
}
```

It seems as though the '\' causes the newlines to be ignored.  Ok fine, I am used to this in bash, but if I put '\' the second one doesn't show up.  As if the second one is absorbed.   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the HTML tags <pre><code> in succession.  I find this easier for pasting code into the window.

```
#define PRINT(x, format, ...)
if ( x ) 
{
    if ( debug_fd != NULL ) 
    { 
        fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##VA_ARGS); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        fprintf(stdout, format, ##VA_ARGS); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add at least four spaces or a hard tab before each line of the code. Like this:

```
#define PRINT(x, format, ...) \
if ( x ) { \
    if ( debug_fd != NULL ) { \
        fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##VA_ARGS); \
} \
else { \
    fprintf(stdout, format, ##VA_ARGS); \
} \
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define PRINT(x, format, ...)
if ( x ) 
{
    if ( debug_fd != NULL ) 
    { 
        fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##VA_ARGS); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        fprintf(stdout, format, ##VA_ARGS); 
    } 
}
```